Stripe Integration - Elements cannot be mounted in a ShadowRoot. Please mount in the Light DOM
I am trying to use Stripe Elements in a react application created with vite. Here is my current code.
 import { CardCvcElement, CardExpiryElement, CardNumberElement, useElements, useStripe } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { StripeCardNumberElement } from "@stripe/stripe-js";
import { useState } from "react";
import { Button, Input, Modal, notify } from "../../shared";
import { PaymentMethodModalProps } from "../../types/paymentMethod.types";
import { transformError } from "../../utils/errors";
const stripeKey = import.meta.env.VITE_APP_STRIPE_KEY;
const PaymentMethodModal = ({
  paymentMethodModal,
  setPaymentMethodModal,
  onPaymentMethod,
  type,
}: PaymentMethodModalProps) => {
  const stripe = useStripe();
  const elements = useElements();
  const [cardHolderName, setCardHolderName] = useState("");
  const handleUpdatePaymentMethod = async (event: any) => {
    event.preventDefault();
    try {
      if (!stripe || !elements) {
        return;
      }
      console.log("cardElement", elements.getElement(CardNumberElement));
      const cardNumberElement: StripeCardNumberElement | null = elements.getElement(CardNumberElement);

      if (cardNumberElement === null) return;

      const { token } = await stripe.createToken(cardNumberElement);
      onPaymentMethod(token?.id || "", cardHolderName);
      setPaymentMethodModal && setPaymentMethodModal(false);
    } catch (error) {
      notify(transformError(error), "error");
    }
  };

  return (
    <Modal
      heading={`${type === "add" ? "Add" : "Update"} payment method`}
      open={paymentMethodModal || false}
      setOpen={setPaymentMethodModal || (() => {})}
      okText={`${type === "add" ? "Add" : "Update"}`}
      onOk={(e) => handleUpdatePaymentMethod(e)}
    >
      <>
        <div className="flex justify-between items-center space-x-3">
          <Input
            onChange={(e) => {
              setCardHolderName(e.target.value);
            }}
            className="mt-3 w-full"
            id="name"
            required={true}
            label="Card holder name"
          />
        </div>
        <div className="mt-3 pr-6 max-w-full">
          <p className="py-1">Card number</p>
          <CardNumberElement className="border-white-400 px-3 py-3 border border-solid rounded-lg w-full" />
        </div>
        <div className="flex space-x-3 mt-3 w-full">
          <div className="w-1/2">
            <p className="py-1">Exp. Date</p>
            <CardExpiryElement className="border-white-400 px-3 py-3 border border-solid rounded-lg" />
          </div>
          <div className="w-1/2">
            <p className="py-1">CVV/CVS</p>
            <CardCvcElement className="border-white-400 px-3 py-3 border border-solid rounded-lg" />
          </div>
        </div>
        <Button onClick={(e) => handleUpdatePaymentMethod(e)}>Whatever</Button>
      </>
    </Modal>
  );
};

export default PaymentMethodModal;

I have wrapped this component inside Elements
import { Elements } from "@stripe/react-stripe-js";
import { loadStripe } from "@stripe/stripe-js";

 <Elements stripe={loadStripe(stripeKey)}>
{component wrapped here}
</Elements>

For some reason, I face this error and the application crashed.

IntegrationError: Elements cannot be mounted in a ShadowRoot. Please mount in the Light DOM.

What I have tried.
As I am using the modal, I tried to use this component outside modal. The error still shows up but the form is rendered correctly and card was working fine.
